# LSTM: how to use just context?

Tags: keras, lstm

I would like to use a model with a bidirectional LSTM layer to predict a sequence of outputs from a sequence of inputs (of length $l$).

To compute the output $o_i$ I would like to use the inputs $x_1, \dots, x_{i-1}$ (the result of the LSTM units up to $i-1$ from the forward pass), and inputs $x_l, \dots, x_{i+1}$ (the result of units $l, \dots, i+1$ from the backwards pass).

In other words I want to exclude input $x_i$ for the LSTM layer's (and network's) output $o_i$.

Does this operation have a name? Is there a simple way to do this in keras or other popular frameworks? Is there some alternative way to achieve the same?